# html when pointing to the picture, it will turn grey with optional text

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the html website

```
<h1>Project</h1>
<img src="images/490_poster.jpg" class="img_p1" style="width:400px;height:300px ;">
```

If the user is pointing to the jpg picture, it will dark slightly and show text "my project". Any help would appreciate to help me find out. Is that any term or any method to make the picture for more detail?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change height, width etc. in .image-popup in CSS just to see how it is working

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
.image-wrap {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-popup {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom:4px;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image-wrap:hover .image-popup {
  opacity: 1;
}
.image-popup2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: rgba(189, 195, 199, 1);
  position: absolute;
  bottom:4px;
  left: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center; 
  padding-top: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.image-wrap:hover .image-popup2 {
  opacity: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <div class="image-popup">My Project</div>
    <img src="https://www2.lbl.gov/Publications/annual-report/2005-2006/assets/img/01-splash-XBD200304-00209-006.jpg" alt="image"> 
  </div>
<div class="image-wrap">
  <div class="image-popup2">My Project<br>(I changed opacity for this one)</div>
    <img src="https://www2.lbl.gov/Publications/annual-report/2005-2006/assets/img/01-splash-XBD200304-00209-006.jpg" alt="image"> 
  </div>
```

Comment: **Note:** The overlay's have a set `height` and `width`

Answer (score 2):

First, add a div.overlay just after your image. Enclose them with a div.container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="overlay">
        <!-- text goes here -->
    </div>
    <!-- image -->
</div>
```

You can use CSS simple styling for this:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
 }
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    aligh-items: center;
    background: #00000088; /* or anything */
}

.img_p1:hover {
    filter: brightness(50%) contrast(150%); /* any fancy filter stuff you might want to add */
}

.container:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I hope that works, I haven't tested the code... (This is literally my first answer ever)
Thanks for reading!

Comment: This is also the way I would go, except you need to change your hover to .container, not image.  The .overlay div lies within the former, not inside the image.

Comment: @jae.phoenix Agreed, let me change the code. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

Source [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_fade)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fade in Overlay</h2>
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos//400/300.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Hello World</div>
  </div>
</div>
```